# Store 32 bit value as C string in most efficient form

Tags: c++, string, hash, compression, hex

I am trying to find the most efficient way to encode 32 bit hashed string values into text strings for transmission/logging in low bandwidth environments. Complex compression can't be used because the hash values need to be contained in human readable text strings when logged and sent between client and host.

Consider the following contrived examples:

given the key/value map

```
table[0xFE12ABCD] = "models/texture/red.bmp";
table[0x3EF088AD] = "textures/diagnostics/pink.jpg";
```

and the string formats:

```
"Loaded asset (0x%08x)"
"Replaced (0x%08x) with (0x%08x)"
```

they could be printed as:

```
"Loaded asset models/texture/red.bmp"
"Replaced models/texture/red.bmp with textures/diagnostics/pink.jpg"
```

Or if the key/value map is known by the client and server:

```
"Loaded asset (0xFE12ABCD)"
"Replaced (0xFE12ABCD) with (0x3EF088AD)"
```

The receiver can then scan for the (0xNNNNNNNN) pattern and expand it locally.

This is what I am doing right now but I would like to find a way to represent the 32 bit value more efficiently. A simple step would be to use a better identifying token:

```
"Loaded asset $FE12ABCD"
"Replaced $1000DEEE with $3EF088AD"
```

Which already reduces the length of each token - $ is not used anywhere else so it is reasonable.

However, what other options are there to make that 32 bit value even smaller? I can't use an index - it has to be a full 32 bit value because in some cases the generator of the string has the hash and sometimes it has a string it will hash immediately.

Comment: You could use *base 64 encoding* / "uuencoding"... google will turn up more than enough information about it.  In short, each character takes on one of 64 printable values, instead of the 16 used for hex.

Comment: This sounds reasonable - I found an online example that takes "FFFFFFFF" (8 characters) and gives me "D/////" (6 characters) which is better. I will check if I can actually use a shifted range of 128 characters to get even better compression. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is [Ascii85 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) which encodes 4 bytes to 5 bytes.

Comment: Anton - that's great I will take a look. 5 bytes plus an identifying token is half the size of the original (0xFFFFFFFF) format. Meaningful messages can now fit into 32 byte strings: "Loaded !NNNNN over !NNNNN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to use Base-85 coding.  You can code four bytes into five Base-85 digits, since 85<sup>5</sup> > 2<sup>32</sup>.  Pick 85 printable characters and assign them to the digit values 0..84.  Then do base conversion to go either way.  Since there are 94 printable characters in ASCII, it is usually easy to find 85 that are "safe" in whatever constrains your strings to be "readable".

Comment: Mark, Anton, this is the approach I took today. An space followed by ! and five characters followed by another space, EOL or Null character is the pattern I use to decode. I have written utility method to make printing them easy enough with format strings as well. Reduces original format of (0xNNNNNNNN) with ! NNNNN which is a good savings in my use case. Thanks again.